# Line in 5/6 sounds awful

Tags: mixer

Bought a Behringer XENYX1202. When I plug in a 1/4 cable into the mic lines (1-4), everything sounds fantastic. However, when I plug the same cable into 5/6 it sounds pretty awful until I pull it out part way, and then it sounds better.

Are different cables required for the lines in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the 5/6 jack is a stereo jack designed for a 3 pin 1/4" connector.  If you are feeding it a mono feed, it is going to have issues.  When you pull it out part way, you remove the sleeve contact point and make it go back to being a single mono connection.

If you want to use it as two mono channels that are stereo linked, you will need to get a L/R adapter cable so that you can feed in one 1/4" for the left side and 1/4" for the right side unless you have an actual stereo input for it.

Comment: "If you are feeding it a mono feed, it is going to have issues... when you pull it out part way... it [goes] back to being a single mono connection."

I don't understand. It seems like you're saying it being a single mono is bad, but when I pull it out part way, it sounds better. I'm truly ignorant of most of the terms you're using, so your patience is appreciated.

Comment: No, mono isn't a bad thing.  Plugging mono in to stereo is a bad thing as you end up trying to drive two signals off of one signal, which means the signal is underpowered for what you are trying to draw off it. (basically).  When you switch back to only feeding one signal, it works better.

Comment: Ah, ok, so by feeding it one signal, i.e., pulling out a little, you're saying it effectively becomes a mono line with a mono feed in it, so it works?

Comment: So it's probably best to just use a 1/8 to dual 1/4 because then the signal is going into both lines in and it's strong enough to be drawn.